# AppEngine deploy error - HttpIoException: Error posting to URL

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Today we start recieving this message when trying to deploy.

```
    ...
    Scanned 8750 files.
    Scanned 9000 files.
    Scanned 9250 files.
    Scanned 9500 files.
    Scanned 9750 files.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 711 static files.
    Cloning 9233 application files.
    Cloned 2000 files.
    Cloned 4000 files.
    Cloned 6000 files.
    Cloned 8000 files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 0 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.
    Rolling back the update.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=facturanube&version=1&
500 Internal Server Error
<h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>


Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy6314649189927600314.log
```

Debugging information file contents:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=si-nube&version=1&
500 Internal Server Error
<h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:303)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:254)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:233)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1100)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.deploy(AppVersionUpload.java:949)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.commit(AppVersionUpload.java:850)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:176)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:151)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:474)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:400)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Important considerations:

- The appengine-web.xml file has no errors.
- We tried deploying in different versions with no success.
- The application can be deployed in another appengine application, but not in our production application.
- We have no cuota-related problems. Our payments have no
  problems.

Our current versions:

GWT SDK 2.4.0

App Engine 1.9.54

Java 7

**Update**

*I was able to deploy today (2018/03/18) with no changes to code or configuration files. I guess Google did something to solve the issue.*

Comment: Have the same issue with Java, I've already opened a ticket with Google and there is also an issue on the tracker. issuetracker.google.com/issues/74877619

Comment: We tested again using JAVA8 in the project and it deployed correctly. I hope there is another solution, because we are still testing this JAVA8 version.

Answer (score 0):

`500 A server error has occurred` on deployment is usually related to malformed configs, including app.yaml and cron.yaml (and Java equivalents). Or if unsupported stanzas are included. Please check your GAE app configs and attempt to strip them down to the essentials just to narrow down which stanzas/flags are messing up the deployment.